# Shell Script Writing Variables Referenced In A File To File

Tags: shell

Running into an issue that is likely simple for people that know how. I am writing an .sh script that reads in a file that has variable names in it. I am trying to use the file following this with the values of the variables in place for the names in the file.

**My Attempted .sh Script:**

```
HELLOVAR = "hello"
cat infilename.json > outfilename.json
```

I then attempt to use outfilename.json, but it has not changed from the original infile.

**File In Example:**

```
I would like this to be ${HELLOVAR}.
```

**File Out Wanted:**

```
I would like this to be hello.
```

Comment: Surely you get an error of the form `HELLOVAR: command not found`.  If not, show us your actual code.

Comment: Do you need to worry about `HELLOVAR='hello "cruel" world'` (which, to be included in a JSON string, would need to be changed to `hello \"cruel\" world`), or is your data pre-escaped to be JSON-safe? (If it's the former, you should use `jq` instead of `envsubst`; it's perfectly capable of looking up environment variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want:

```
HELLOVAR=hello envsubst < infilename.json > outfilename.json
```

`envsubst` reads its input stream looking for simple variable expressions (eg, it will substitute `$FOO` and `${FOO}`, but will not perform the expected substitution on expressions like `${FOO-bar}`) and expands them according to the current setting in the environment.  `HELLOVAR=hello envsubst` invokes `envsubst` with HELLOVAR set to `hello` in its environment.

Comment: This is problematic if any of the values require escaping. I'd argue that this would be better resolved by the answers to [Replacing variables in a JSON template using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976258/replacing-variables-in-a-json-template-using-jq)

Comment: (maybe not that one; I know we have a Q&A entry somewhere with jq code that searches a document's strings for `${varname}` references and looks up the named variables in `env`)

Comment: Would there be a way to achieve this without actual saving the output file. Instead just have it be usable in the script itself?

Comment: @toren It depends on what you mean.  There are a lot of options.  You could pipe the output of `envsubst` into some command block, or you could save its output to a variable, or you could run `envsubst` inside a heredoc, or any number of other methods for making the data available to the script.  But storing it on the filesystem is a pretty good method.